# Ignore a git directory in composer package

Tags: git, github, composer-php, ignore, packagist

I have composer library hosted as a package on Packagist through GitHub. The repository includes a directory named `sample` with some samples on how to use the code and this directory is really not needed when using the package.

Is there a way to have this directory ignored when you do `composer update/install`?

Comment: maybe use --prefer-source and remove that dir from that package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You technically can using the .gitattributes and the export-ignore directive. See http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Exporting-Your-Repository for more details.